# What core function do Magento call for default store view

Tags: function, magento, model

Can someone tell me what core function do Magento call for default store view to be set on the frontend?

I searched it for hours in Mage/Core/Model and didn't found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method links provided for convenience.

1. [`Mage::run('','store')`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/index.php#L87)
2. [`Mage_Core_Model_App::run(array(array('scope_code'=>'','scope_type'=>'store')))`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/Mage.php#L679)
3. [`Mage_Core_Model_App::_initCurrentStore('','store')`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php#L349)
4. [`Mage_Core_Model_App::_initStores('','store')`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php#L466)

Within `_initStores()` is a [loop which iterates over the `core_store` collection](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php#L643). The loop contains a test to see if the App instance's `_store` property is set, and if not, sets it to the current collection member *if that member has a primary key which evaluates to true*. In other words, despite the fact that the admin store is the first item in the collection, because its ID is 0, it will *not* be used.

Comment: Wow awesome... Thank you very much benmarks, your detail answer really help me a lot. Now I know how Magento set the store view. I hope people read this thread also helped. :D

Answer (score 0):

this would be in index.php

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

get more details on how it is exactly done from this cool blog article http://blog.belvg.com/magento-certified-developer-exam-module-initialization.html that covers about everything you need to know about this.

Comment: Thank you. But I thought, there must be a core function should do that. And it explained well by benmarks. :)

Comment: yeah well Ben just brought you the contents of the link I posted